# How to Make a Copy of a database?

Tags: sql-server

I have an sql server database and I want to make a mirror copy of it on my local computer. I tried to use the copy database wizard but it fails. It seems me to look at the event log for the reason but all it says in the event log is

```
Package "CDW_4" failed.
```

so I have no clue why it is failing.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that by mirror copy ==> you mean at the point when the database full backup was taken.

If that is not the case, then for **near to realtime** copy of your database, I would suggest [transactional replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx).

Also, if you are using enterprise edition, then you can leverage the benefits of [database SNAPSHOTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx).

**Step 1: Make a FULL database backup**

```
backup database database_name to disk = 'path to backup drive' with copy_only, stats =10
-- ,compression (sql server 2008 R2 and up, compression is available in standard edition as well).
```

> e.g. path to backup drive = D:\backups\db_name_FULL.bak

**Step 2: Restore the backup taken in step 1 `with move`.**

```
restore database database_name_mirror
from disk = 'path to backup drive'
with stats =10, recovery,
move 'Logical_Data_FileName' to 'Physical data file location.mdf',
move 'Logical_Log_FileName' to 'Physical log file location.ldf'
```

Logical file name can be found using `sp_helpdb database_name` or `restore filelistonly from disk = D:\backups\db_name_FULL.bak`

e.g.

```
restore database database_name_mirror
from disk='D:\backups\db_name_FULL.bak'
WITH move 'database_name_Data' to  'D:\Data\database_name_mirror_Data.mdf',
move 'database_name_log' to  'L:\logs\database_name_mirror_log.ldf';
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want full copy for your local instance, just get the latest full backup. If you need to make a backup, make sure you use `WITH COPY_ONLY` to not affect recovery for production.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could:

1. Detach the db.
2. Copy the db files and rename them.
3. Reattach the original.
4. Attach the new database and alter the name to attach it as (and the filenames).

Not pretty but it just worked for me.

edit: i'd like to add this would not be my first choice. Shawn & Kins Backup/Restore suggestions are better. I just chucked it in there as a plan B. (or C.. or D..)

Comment: Very bad idea. Why would you detach, rename and attach - **causing downtime** for such a simple task that can be done using **backup and restore** ?

Comment: I know it's not ideal. but it *is* an alternative. Detaching would remove the possibility of locking issues. The OP doesn't mention uptime/availability as an issue.